# Jquery detect event on click only

Tags: jquery, events

I want to add some code after a jQuery event has occurred on a form after a click event only. The event is also called when other events occur.

If I use this code it detects the event being called:

```
      $( ".grouped_form" ).on("wc_variation_form", function() {
        alert("triggered");
      });
```

The best solution i've been able to come up with is this, but it doesn't work:

```
$( ".grouped_form" ).on("click", function() {
      $(this).on("wc_variation_form", function() {
        alert("triggered");
      });
    });
```

Is there a way to detect when this event is triggered by a click event only?

Comment: What is the `wc_variation_form` event?

Comment: It's the last event in the sequence. The reason I want to do this is because I made some changes to the html, and a whole sequence of events gets triggered by clicking the button. Everything works as expected, but it changes the visibility of some elements. I figured I'd fix the html at the end of all the events being triggered.

Comment: I meant I've never heard of an event called `wc_variation_form`. Is it a custom event of your application?

Comment: Yes, it's from woocommerce. This is the code where it triggers `t.trigger("wc_variation_form"), a.loading = !1
    }, 100)
  };'

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.click').click(function(){
  $(this).addClass('clicked');
})

$('.trigger').click(function(){
  if($('.click').hasClass('clicked')){
    // Your codes
    console.log('triggered');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Click thi button before trigger. otherwise you can not get a result.</div>
<button class="click">Click</button>
<div>Click this button for trigger the event</div>
<button class="trigger">Trigger</button>
```

You can use jquery adaClass and hasClass methods fot this

Comment: Thanks, I tried this, but I think the elements get refreshed, because the "clicked" class was removed, and therefore wouldn't trigger.

Answer (score 1):

Try next modiffication and tellme if works at expected:

```
$(".grouped_form").on("click", function() {
    $(this).one("wc_variation_form", function() {
        alert("triggered");
    });
});
```

It will register the listener of event "wc_variaton_form" only one time after a click events occurs.

Comment: Are you sure the event "wc_variation_form" is triggered on the target ".grouped_from" after a click event ocurrs on the same target? Can you try next thing: **1)** Start a timer when you code begins: `console.time("test")`, **2)** Add next listeners to the target `$(".grouped_form").on("click wc_variation_fom", function() {console.timeLog("test")})` **3)** Check the developer console for times and the sequence order of events.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure - when I used the first code block and clicked the button it triggered at the end of the sequence. Getting an error on step 2 - TypeError: console.timeLog is not a function.

Comment: OK, then replace for this **1)** start 2 timers: console.time("test1"); console.time("test2"); **2)** $(".grouped_form").on("click", function() {console.timeEnd("test1")}); $(".grouped_form").on("wc_variation_form", function() {console.timeEnd("test2")}); **3)** Is the same check.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I found a solution. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've ended up solving this, but the answers have helped me realise what the problem is. After the click event occurs, some parts of the page get refreshed, and the click event isn't linked to the other events. The solution is to store a variable on the click event, and then reset it when the next event occurs.

```
var clicked = localStorage['clicked'];

    $( ".grouped_form" ).on("click", function() {
      localStorage['clicked'] = "true";
  });

      $(".grouped_form").on("wc_variation_form", function() {
        if (clicked == "true") {
          localStorage['clicked'] = "false";
          alert("triggered");
      }
    });
```